# How to return multiple values from "case" statement in ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

There are multiple countries in a stream, and there are different transformations for each country.
For example:

For IN country:
AddressId rename to ID, **Steet rename to county**, **PostCode rename to Zip**, CountryCode.
For TW country:
AddressId rename to ID, **County rename to county**, **PostalCode rename to Zip**, CountryCode.

How can we combine these two transformations into one stream?

CASE
WHEN CountryCode == 'IN' THEN AddressId as ID, Street as county, PostCode as Zip
WHEN CountryCode == 'TW' THEN AddressId as ID, County as county, PostalCode as Zip

How can I achieve the above transformations?